# Possible to create a temporary streamobject as an argument for a function?

Tags: c++, stringstream

I have this function which should take an optional stream argument to print as an errortext.

```
void showUsage(std::wstringstream oErrortext, bool bExit, int nExitCode)
{
    if(oErrortext.rdbuf()->in_avail() > 0)
        std::wcerr << oErrortext << std::endl;

    std::wcout << gUsage << std::endl;

    if(bExit == true)
        exit(nExitCode);
}
```

Now when I try to call this with a single argument, it works fine:

```
showUsage(std::wstringstream(L"Multiple filenames for target found"), true, 10);
```

But the reason why I wanted to use stringstream is, to be able to construct a generaetd string, not just static strings.

Example:

```
showUsage(std::wstringstream(L"Number format for offset missing -") << oParam->mOption, true, 10);
```

But I get a compilation error with this.

1. How can I create this temporary object and stream the parameters with a single line (or do I have to create it first anyway so it wouldn't be possible with a single line)?
2. Is there a better solution to what I'm trying to do here (not messing with varargs)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `string` instead of a stream:

```
void showUsage(std::wstring oErrortext, bool bExit, int nExitCode)
{
    if (!oErrortext.empty())
        std::wcerr << oErrortext << std::endl;
    ...
}
```

To use it, concatenate strings with `+`:

```
showUsage(std::wstring(L"Number format missing -") + oParam->mOption, true, 10);
```

My system has an incompatible return type for `operator<<` of `stringstream` (it returns a reference to `ostream`, not a reference to `stringstream`), so it's impossible to append stuff to a `stringstream` and send it to a function in a single line of code (it might be possible to use a `static_cast`, but you certainly don't want this ugly hack). So, unless this is an implementation bug (unlikely!), you must do large changes your code, like suggested above.

Answer (score 0):

I propose you to use a reference for the stringstream:

```
std::wstringstream& showUsage(std::wstringstream& oErrortext, bool bExit, int nExitCode)
```

(note the **&**)

Copying streams seems to be an issue. (Thinking of what happens with source and destination...)

If you pass it like you did, a copy of the string is needed. You can avoid this by call by reference.